# Error C3867 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have this piece of code, 
I don't understand why it is displaying this error?

```
string messege = "aaa";
char tmp[50];
strcpy_s(tmp, messege.length(), messege.c_str);
char* s = NULL;
s = &(tmp[0]);
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What line is the error on?  That's where you should focus the initial investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line, you've forgotten the parentheses after the call to `c_str`:

```
strcpy_s(tmp, messege.length(), messege.c_str);
```

Adding the missing parentheses should fix this.

That said, it's unusual to want to mix C-style and C++-style strings this way. You may want to think about whether what you're doing is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`c_str` is a member function of `std::string`, so you need to call it with `()`

```
strcpy_s(tmp, messege.length(), messege.c_str());
```

This will solve your problem.